# Script Error: NullReferenceException: downloadhandler.data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Error in the script, at [www.downloadHandler.data](http://www.downloadHandler.data), Error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
    private IEnumerator LoadBytes(string path, System.Action<byte[]> action) {

        UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(path);

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        action(www.downloadHandler.data);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the constructor of [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-ctor.html) creates a generic web request and you would have to set it up completely manually!

> Creates a `UnityWebRequest` with the default options and **no attached DownloadHandler or UploadHandler**.

Going this way you would need to set it manually

```
www.downloadHanlder = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
```

before starting the request.

---

In general what you rather want to use is [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) which already fully configures the `UnityWebRequest` in order to successfully perform a GET request.

This is somewhat comparable to e.g. using `Socket` vs `TcpClient`.

---

Then you should anyway always check if the request was successful at all.

(Also see the example from the API)

```
private IEnumerator LoadBytes(string path, System.Action<byte[]> action) 
{
    using(var www = UnityWebRequest.Get(path))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        switch (webRequest.result)
        {
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                Debug.LogError("Error: " + webRequest.error);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                Debug.LogError("HTTP Error: " + webRequest.error);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                action?.Invoke(www.downloadHandler.data);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```